# J-2 visa renewal

Tags: usa, visa, canada, indian-citizens, j-visa

Im a J-2 visa holder and Indian citizen. My husband is canadian and J-1 holder. Both our DS-2019 are valid. But visas expired. I had to travel to canada recently and now im here. In order to reenter US i understand i will have to renew J-2 visa.
My question is :

1. For renewal is the procedure same as first time application? with all prolonged wait time and interview etc.Or is there a lockbox facility to drop off documents and get renewed.?

Comment: If your travel to Canada is under 30 days and you don't apply for a new visa, you may be eligible for [automatic revalidation](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html) allowing you to return to the US with your expired visa.

Comment: Normally, the process is basically the same.  For example, you'll need to go for an interview.  But the decision shouldn't take a long time since you're just applying to return to your residence in the US. However, I have no idea how the COVID-19 pandemic affects any of this, which is why I'm paying this as a comment rather than an answer.  If you find out, please come back and pay your own answer to this question.

Comment: yes so i was told that you can waive the interview if u are applying for renewal, unlike the first time visa application and that one can use their lockbox facility to drop off documents. is it true?